# Want to go Specifc page in PDF using WebView

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview, pdf-viewer

I am using Web View to Display PDF and it is working fine But I want to go to a specific page but it is not working as in WebView we have to use URL so I am Passing my page number in the URL that is working on a desktop browser. i.e.[URL](https://www.holybooks.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/The-Holy-Bible-King-James-Version.pdf#page=4)
else if you know any other way to show PDF in the app that will be most welcomed but if you talk about barteck PDFviewer library that will not work for me because of the massive size. I want a simple lightweight PDF Viewer that redirects me to a specific page. Any suggestion will be welcomed. while using webView my Code is below:

```
progressBar= findViewById(R.id.bar);
        webView= findViewById(R.id.webView);
        progressBar.setMax(100);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        String url= "https://www.holybooks.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/The-Holy-Bible-King-James-Version.pdf#page=4";
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//        webView.hasFocus();
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        webView.loadUrl(
                "https://docs.google.com/gvview?embedded=true&url="+ url);
        //https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=
        //https://docs.google.com/gvview?embedded=true&url= #page=4
progressBar.setProgress(0);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
        progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
        if(newProgress==100){
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else
        {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
    }
});

        int number = intent.getIntExtra("numberpg", 0);
        String number1 = String.valueOf(number);

    }
}
```

Comment: `am using Web View to Display PDF` That is impossible as a WebView cannot display a pdf document to begin with.

Comment: So how to go to a specific page other than bartacks library

Comment: `am using Web View to Display PDF ` I would not only say such if i did the things you do. I would say that i used a google service to convert a pdf document in a html page and used WebView to display that html. As said before a webview cannot display a pdf document.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this library which worked for me

[pdf download and load pdf library process](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer)

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-load-pdf-from-url-in-android/

and this is the pdf view library

[pdf library mention in the the blog(link) above](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer)

After that you can open pdf using

`pdfView.fromStream(InputStream).defaultPage(yourpagenumber).load`

After reading these 2 link , I hope you will get what you wanted...

Comment: No bro that library works fine but I have a size issue with this library. That's why I had to choose other way to implement this. If you know how to reduce size that will be helpful for me